# How to use javascript fields combined with array instead of repeating function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, field

I have the following Javascript (pure):

```
const style = document.documentElement.style;

**var ranges = {
    'tx': [-15, 15, 0], // key = css style property, first value = start range random, second value = end range random, third value = initial vlaue to return to
    'ty': [-5, 5, 0],
    'scale': [0.5, 1.5, 1],
    'opacity': [0.5, 0.9, 0]
};**

function valueChange(prop, value, initial) {
  style.setProperty('--' + prop, value);
  setTimeout ( function() {
    style.setProperty('--' + prop, initial);
  }, 150)
}

var timer = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      **for (key in ranges) {
        valueChange(key, randomBetween(ranges[key][0], ranges[key][1]), ranges[key][2]);
      };**
    }, 150);
}, false);           

function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Its task is to set CSS properties by random when a scroll ends and then automatically let them return to an initial value.

What is interesting for me is not the result itself but the errors I seemingly did here. I think it is a mere spelling/understanding JS problem from my side.

As I already had a working code which is this one:

```
const style = document.documentElement.style;

function valueChange(prop, value, initial) {
  style.setProperty('--' + prop, value);
  setTimeout ( function() {
    style.setProperty('--' + prop, initial);
  }, 150)
}

var timer = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      **var newX = randomBetween(-15, 15);
      var newY = randomBetween(-5, 5);
      var newScale = randomBetween(0.5, 1.5);
      var newOpacity = randomBetween(0.5, 0.9);
      valueChange('tx', newX + 'vw', 0);
      valueChange('ty', newY + 'vw', 0);
      valueChange('scale', newScale, 1);
      valueChange('opacity', newOpacity, 0);**
    }, 150);
}, false);           

function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

So what I am basically trying to achieve is to *replace* the bold displayed code parts, in order to make the script more professional, less repetitive.

Let’s say I am willing to share the idea with someone but I’d like to avoid to use “stupid” code (even if working fine).

Someone there who could help me with that?

**EDIT:**

So I had to use:

```
var ranges = {
    'tx': [-15, 15, 0, 'vw'],
    'ty': [-5, 5, 0, 'vw'],
    'scale': [0.5, 1.5, 1, ''],
    'opacity': [0.5, 0.9, 0, '']
};
```

and:

```
for (key in ranges) {
    valueChange(key, randomBetween(ranges[key][0], ranges[key][1]) + ranges[key][3], ranges[key][2]);
};
```

Comment: What's not working? On first read it seems logical, except that the `tx` and `ty` lines are missing the `+ 'vw'`.

Comment: Here: `valueChange('tx', newX + 'vw', 0)` You need `+ 'vw'` for the first 2 keys

Comment: Good point! Thanks! So I did it in the following way (see EDIT) as I couldn’t insert it in the random function. I just wonder now if that construct really looks better than the original repeating function :-))